Bamboo unable to extract changes between revision
I have a Bamboo pipeline which is triggered when bitbucket PR is merged. However, there's been an issue where Bamboo is not able to extract changes between revision and the user who invoke the change is shown as "unknown".
I noticed there's a confluence page from Bamboo stating that this issue might be caused by rebase or force push in bitbucket (ref: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/bamboo-was-unable-to-extract-changes-between-revisions-1319249071.html).
However, there isn't any solution to this problem, and I am getting this "unknown" user for all my subsequent build. Kindly advise any solution to resolve this issue.
